# How do you programmatically get the serial number of an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know the serial number of my iPhone using my application.  I have writen code below.

```
- (NSString*)getSerialNumber
{
 CFTypeRef serialNumberAsCFString;

 io_service_t platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));

 if (platformExpert)
 {
     serialNumberAsCFString = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, CFSTR(kIOPlatformUUIDKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
 }

 IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);

 NSString *serial = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",serialNumberAsCFString];

    NSLog(@"serail no==>%@",serialNumberAsCFString);
    NSLog(@"serail no==>%@",serial);
}
```

Why am I still getting wrong serial number?

Comment: What do you mean "wrong serial number"? Is it not showing up, or just incorrect?

Comment: do you need the serial number or the UUID? Apple docs say that UUID is unique among all devices and that you should use such number instead Device Serial Number.

Comment: is that accepted by Apple Store?

Answer (score 5):

You should change the argument 2 of `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty` from `CFSTR (kIOPlatformUUIDKey)` to `CFSTR (kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey)`. Then you will get the correct serial number(with length of 11 characters).

Answer (score 2):

Are you linking the IOKit framework?

Try the

```
id getValue(NSString *iosearch);
```

function, available at

http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/08/retrieving-device-information.html

You can also use the UIDevice class to retrieve other useful information
For instance, you can do:

```
NSString *id = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

Other useful properties are the following ones:

```
  name  
  systemName    
  systemVersion  
  model  
  localizedModel
```

Comment: ok I have try this code , but my application is terminated improperly & give me warnings at 3 places:
1) CFTypeId propID=NULL; (pointer without cast)
2) CFTypeRef prop = IORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty(entry,
              kIODeviceTreePlane, iosearch, nil, 
              kIORegistryIterateRecursively);( warning: passing argument 3 of 'IORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty' from incompatible pointer type
)

Answer (score 0):

Ready to use category on UIDevice: [UIDevice+serialNumber](http://gist.github.com/566994). Not sure this would be accepted on the App Store.