# Retrieving UDID via private API

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, udid

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the UDID on devices running iOS 6+ (Enterprise deployment only - no app store limitations).

Calling the (now private) method `uniqueIdentifier` returns the 'vendorIdentifier' starting with 'FFFFFFF'. Unfortunately thats not what I want.

Any ideas? Is there another private method or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you need the udid?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/theiostream/lockdown-uiduid/blob/master/main.mm

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you reading [this article](http://blog.appsfire.com/udid-is-dead-openudid-is-deprecated-long-live-advertisingidentifier/). To sum up:

- The previously deprecated `uniqueIdentifier` now works like `vendorIdentifier` on iOS 7+, so it's no longer usable even for Enterprise Apps
- [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) cannot be shared between Applications on iOS 7+ and now can change. It's still usable but no longer recommended.
- The `vendorIdentifier` hasn't changed, but it's not recommended for Enterprise Apps because it can change when updating the App.
- The new [`advertisingIdentifier` API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html) is the way to go for new Apps. It's the same for all Apps and should not change frequently, but the user can reset it in the settings page.

Edit: Website [udid.io](http://get.udid.io) obtains the real Device UDID instead of the obfuscated one if you need it for anything outside your App. If you need the UDID from within the App, see my answer above.

Comment: Well, I know OpenUDID. The problem is though that our (legacy) backend is returning data based on UDIDs. I was looking for a solution which doesn't involve refactoring server side applications. People just had to copy & paste their UDID from iTunes and they were ready to go.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but on iOS 7+ there's no way to access the UDID shown in iTunes from code anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a Unique UDID via this method using private api. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036415/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-retrieve-the-device-serial-number-of-an-ios-device-u)
Look for the code in accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I only get **some** Unique id - not the particular UDID shown in iTunes.

Comment: Well thats strange - I will relook into code tomo and let you know because I thought I was getting the same UDID that we see in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but Apple warned it would be deprecated and it has been. I've had the same headache myself.

I can't help you identify the device in the same way Apple do, but you can always generate an unique UUID on app launch and stash that away in KeyChain. It won't be perfect, but it will persist between installations and will be unique to the device. As far as I know, that's the current solution