# Get serial number of device using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, serial-number

Does anyone know how to retrieve a device's serial number using xamarin forms in C#?

I have researched a lot and tried some but could not get it work.

I am trying to develop a mobile application and publish to tablets for testing, so I would need to differentiate the devices, or anyone has other alternatives to share?

Comment: Please always include a minimal reproducible example on what you have tried till now to help you better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by serial number!

Comment: @FreakyAli Hi, I am using android tablet. There is a serial number in Status under about device. I would like to get hold of it to differentiate the tablets I will need to publish my apk to.

Comment: Could you get the device id by below method ?

Comment: @Charis If you want to get the hardware serial number,you could check the update below.I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)  to get it each platform.

For android 
`Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);`

For ios

you could refer to the [blog](http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=260) or optionally save the `IdentifierForVendor` e.g. in your `AppDelegate` and return this value in your `IOSDevice` class (using the name in the blogpost).
use `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.ToString()` to get the device ID on iOS.

**Update** :

from iOS 8, we cannot retrieve the serial number of our iDevice directly,if you want to get it,you could follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224410/10768653)

For Android,you could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029386/10768653)