# Xamarin iOS Platform - Get Device Serial# Method - iOS 8 or Later

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

For our project, we are trying to get the Device Serial Number of the iOS device using the Xamarin platform. We do not have direct APIs for retrieving the Serial Number of the device from iOS 8 or later.

We had come across one solution like creating a static library from XCode with Serial Number implementation. Then create the object c static library and binding this to Xamarin.iOS project.

Reference: [What is the simplest way to retrieve the device serial number of an iOS device using MonoTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036415/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-retrieve-the-device-serial-number-of-an-ios-device-u/15224410#15224410)

Is there is any other straight forward approach to accomplish our requirement?

Comment: Apple does not allow this - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/110960

Comment: Does my answer solves your problem? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you post in the question is **out of date** and Apple **does not allow** you to get device serial number right now.

You can have a try to use [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) as the unique device id.

> We had come across one solution like creating a static library from
> XCode with Serial Number implementation. Then create the object c
> static library and binding this to Xamarin.iOS project.

I would like to say that if you find a solution in native iOS, then you can do it in Xamarin.iOS.

You don't need to create a objective-c static library and binding this to Xamarin.iOS project.